# How to fill a new google sheet with all rows that contain a specific value in a different sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

Imagine you have a google sheet which lists your favorite shops, types of shirts they have, and their price in separate columns. To find out which store has which shirts, you wish to filter out all shirts sold by each store into separate sheets. Example sheets are at the bottom of this post.

I have tried using both QUERY and FILTER in the following way:

```
=QUERY('Master sheet'!A:C,"Select * Where A='Shoppy'")

=FILTER('Master sheet'!A:C,(REGEXMATCH('Master sheet'!A2:A=”Shoppy”)))
```

And both fail. Is it because of a syntax error with the queries? Or am I going about this in a very wrong way?

Master sheet looks like this:

| Shop name | Shirt type | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Shoppy | Tshirt | 12$ |
| Shoppy | Polo | 24$ |
| Shoppy | V-neck | 10$ |
| ShopShop | Tshirt | 14$ |
| ShopShop | Polo | 17$ |
| Shooooop | Polo | 10$ |
| Shooooop | V-neck | 42$ |

Output Sheet 1:

| Shop name | Shirt type | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Shoppy | Tshirt | 12$ |
| Shoppy | Polo | 24$ |
| Shoppy | V-neck | 10$ |

Output Sheet 2:

| Shop name | Shirt type | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ShopShop | Tshirt | 14$ |
| ShopShop | Polo | 17$ |

Output Sheet 3:

| Shop name | Shirt type | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Shooooop | Polo | 10$ |
| Shooooop | V-neck | 42$ |

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`REGEXMATCH()` Shouldn't be necessary in the filter function. Try this:

`=filter('Master Sheet'!A2:C, 'Master Sheet'!A2:A="Shoppy")`

Let me know if you have any questions or if something doesn't work for you.

Comment: This works, thanks! Didn't know that Filter() could be used like this

Answer (score 0):

Use **Data > Create a filter** to see rows one shop at a time, instead of using formulas to scatter data to multiple tabs.